# Python web crawler, depth issue

Tags: python, web-crawler

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyyJWZd-V8I) on makin a web crawler in Python. I've managed to get my code up and running but the problem which I have, and in the video above doesn't occur is when I increase the number in `print scraper(url,7)`, which is located at the end of code, to 8 or larger I'm getting an following error in shell:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#30>", line 1, in <module>
  execfile("threads/mechanizex.py")
File "threads/mechanizex.py", line 85, in <module>
  print scraper(url,7)
File "threads/mechanizex.py", line 21, in scraper
  for u in step_url:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

And I don't know what is my problem because I have exactly the same code as author in video, and he increases his number up to 13 and gets result links while I can not increase it over 7. Here is my entire code:

```
import urllib
import re
import time
from threading import Thread
import MySQLdb
import mechanize
import readability
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from readability.readability import Document
import urlparse

url = "http://adbnews.com/area51"

def scraper(root,steps):
    urls = [root]
    visited = [root]
    counter = 0
    while counter < steps:
        step_url = scrapeStep(urls)
        urls = []
        for u in step_url:
            if u not in visited:
                urls.append(u)
                visited.append(u)
        counter +=1

    return visited

def scrapeStep(root):
    result_urls = []
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

    for url in root:
        try:
            br.open(url)
            for link in br.links():
                newurl = urlparse.urljoin(link.base_url, link.url)
                result_urls.append(newurl)
        except:
            print "error"
        return result_urls

d = {}
threadlist = []

def getReadableArticle(url):
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

    html = br.open(url).read()

    readable_article = Document(html).summary()
    readable_title = Document(html).short_title()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(readable_article)

    final_article = soup.text

    links = soup.findAll('img', src=True)

    return readable_title
    return final_article

def dungalo(urls):
    article_text = getReadableArticle(urls)[0]
    d[urls] = article_text

def getMultiHtml(urlsList):
    for urlsl in urlsList:
        try:
            t = Thread(target=dungalo, args=(urls1,))
            threadlist.append(t)
            t.start()
        except:
            nnn = True

    for g in threadlist:
        g.join()

    return d

print scraper(url,7)
```

Help anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong. It must reasonably be this:

```
def scrapeStep(root):
    result_urls = []
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

    for url in root:
        try:
            br.open(url)
            for link in br.links():
                newurl = urlparse.urljoin(link.base_url, link.url)
                result_urls.append(newurl)
        except:
            print "error"

    return result_urls
```

Otherwise it only looks at the first URL given, and also returns None if there were no URLs given.